# Multiple ingress-nginx controllers - how does the class annotation work?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

This https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/ says:

> When running multiple ingress-nginx controllers, it will only process an unset class
> annotation if one of the controllers uses the default --ingress-class value

1. where is this class annotation set and how does it work?
2. what is the default --ingress-class value?

Answer (score 1):

**1.  where is this class annotation set and how does it work?**

The [ingress class](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/#ingress-class) annotation is being set when ingress object is being defined. This concept gives you a way of more than one controller coexisting and not trying to race to satisfy one particular ingress object.

**2.  what is the default --ingress-class value?**

The default Ingress class of NGINX Ingress Controller is `nginx`, which means that it only handles configuration resources with the `class` set to `nginx`. You can customize the class through the `-ingress-class` command-line argument.

Reference: [Configuring Ingress Class](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/#configuring-ingress-class)

So in order to have different ingress class like in the example below:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-controller-1"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 8080
```

You will need to define the same class for the nginx controller that is supose to satisfy that ingress:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: nginx-ingress-internal-controller
           args:
             - /nginx-ingress-controller
             - '--ingress-class=nginx-controller-1'
             - '--configmap=ingress/nginx-ingress-internal-controller'
```